# a-z Regular expression not working in jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, regex

My code looks like this. Help me

```
$('#form').validate({
  errorElement: "span", // contain the error msg in a span tag
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    CountryName: {
      required: true,
      regex: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
    }
  },
  messages: {
    CountryName: {
      required: "Enter Country name",
      regex: "Enter Correct Country name",
    },
  },
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.Net MVC. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `regex` rule, it is called `pattern` and is from the `additional-methods` file

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#form').validate({
    errorElement: "span", // contain the error msg in a span tag
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
      CountryName: {
        required: true,
        pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
      }
    },
    messages: {
      CountryName: {
        required: "Enter Country name",
        pattern: "Enter Correct Country name",
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <input name="CountryName" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for ur help . its works for me. but it display bydefault msg " Invalid Format" instade off my msg "Enter Correct Country name" .  plz tell me wht changes r required  ?

Comment: @SiddharthVarlekar because in messages still `regex` is used